# mat-header-cell are not showing after navigation Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

mat-header-cell appears fine on the page but after navigation to a second page and refreshing the second page in the browser and navigating again to the page, it is not showing on the page. It will appear after refreshing the page in the browser. I spent a lot of time but I am not able to find what is going wrong. I have attached the code below please see it and If anyone knows what is going wrong then please let me know. This issue occurs in production and not in development. Thank you

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    if (this.model instanceof TableMeta) {
      this.table = this.model;
    } else {
      this.table = MetaModelRegistry.get(this.model).table; // get a table config from model reqistry
    }

    this.displayedColumns = combineLatest(this.table.columns.reduce((observables: Observable<boolean>[], col) => {
      // handle showIf property of column
      const show = col.showIf(this.injector, this.route.queryParamMap);
      observables.push(show instanceof Observable ? show : of(show));
      return observables;
    }, [])).pipe(
      map(showCols => {
        const cols = this.table.columns.filter((c, i) => showCols[i])
          .map(c => c.id);
        this.editEnabled && cols.push('edit');
        this.deleteEnabled && cols.push('delete');
        return cols;
      })
    );
    this.displayedFilters = combineLatest( [of(this.table.columns.map(c => c.id))] ).pipe(
        map( ( [cols] ) => {
        const formFields = this.table.filters.fieldSets[0].filter((ff, i) => {
          const id = ff['columnid'] || ff['id'];
          // columnid if present will override id, occasionally needed to sync filter with column for showif
          return cols.includes(id);
        });
        const filters = this.table.filters;
        filters.fieldSets[0] = formFields;
        return filters;
      })
    );
    this.filterQueryParams = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      map(params => {
        params = Object.assign({}, params);
        delete params['page'];
        delete params['pageSize'];
        return params;
      })
    );
    this.editEnabled = this.disableEdit ? false : this.edit.observers.length > 0;
    if (!this.deleteEnabled) this.deleteEnabled = this.delete.observers.length > 0;
    this.paginationEnabled = this.dataSource instanceof PaginatedDataSource;
    if (this.dataSource instanceof PaginatedDataSource) {
      this.pagination = this.dataSource.pagination;
    }
    this.navRoute = this.routerHelper.getPathRoute(this.router);
  }
```

```html
<div [ngClass]="cssClasses">
  <table mat-table multiTemplateDataRows="true" [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container *ngFor='let column of table.columns' [matColumnDef]="column.id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column.name}}</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let value;">
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.def; else defaultDef">
          <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="column | colDef: value"></ng-template>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #defaultDef>
          <a *ngIf='column["href"]' [href]='getCellHref(column, value)'>
            {{getCellValue(column, value)}}
          </a>
          <a *ngIf='column["routerLink"]' [routerLink]='getCellRouterLink(column, value)'
             [queryParams]='getCellRouterParams(column, value)'>
            {{getCellValue(column, value)}}
          </a>
          <span *ngIf='!(column.routerLink||column.href)'>
              {{getCellValue(column, value)}}
            </span>
        </ng-template>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
 <ng-container *ngIf="displayedColumns | async as cols">
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="cols"></tr>
  <tr mat-row class="cbdweb-row-separator" *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['separator']; when: separateRowsFn()">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: cols;"></tr>
</ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

This error message only appears in development when the first time page loads but not in production and the issue appears in the production:

```js
core.js:6498 
        
       ERROR Error: Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot determine which columns should be rendered.
    at getTableMissingRowDefsError (table.js:1107:1)
    at MatTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.js:1491:1)
    at callHook (core.js:2548:1)
    at callHooks (core.js:2507:1)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2458:1)
    at refreshView (core.js:9525:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10655:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9280:1)
    at refreshView (core.js:9534:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10655:1)
```

**meta-model-registry.ts**

```js
import { CBDWebMetaModel } from "./cbdweb-meta-model";
import { TableConfigBuilder } from "./datatable/meta/table";
import { FormConfigBuilder } from "./form";

export namespace MetaModelRegistry {

    const metaModels: CBDWebMetaModel[] = [];
    const builders: CBDWebMetaModelBuilder[] = [];

    export function get(model: any) {
      const metaModel = _find(model.constructor, metaModels);
      if (metaModel) return metaModel;
      const builder = _find(model.constructor, builders);
      if (builder) {
        const metaModel = builder.build();
        builders.splice(builders.indexOf(builder), 1);
        metaModels.push(metaModel);
        return metaModel;
      }
      const formMetaModel = _findFormFormMeta(model.identifiedBy,metaModels);
      if(formMetaModel) return formMetaModel;
    }

    export function getBuilder(constructor: Function): CBDWebMetaModelBuilder {
      const metaModel = _find(constructor, metaModels);
      if (metaModel) throw new Error(`Meta model for ${constructor} already exist`);
      let builder = _find(constructor, builders);
      if (!builder) {
        builder = new CBDWebMetaModelBuilder(constructor);
        builders.push(builder);
      }
      return builder;
    }

    export function safeGet(constructor): CBDWebMetaModel {
        let metaModel = get(new constructor());
        if (!metaModel) {
            metaModel = new CBDWebMetaModel(constructor);
            add(metaModel);
        }
        return metaModel;
    }

    export function add(metaModel: CBDWebMetaModel) {
        metaModels.push(metaModel);
    }

    function _find<T extends {model: Function}>(constructor: Function, arr: T[]): T {
      return arr.find(({model}) => constructor == model);
    }

    function _findFormFormMeta(identifiedBy: string, arr: CBDWebMetaModel[]) {
      return arr.find((model) => identifiedBy == model.identifiedBy);
    }

    class CBDWebMetaModelBuilder {//allows to lazily build a meta model when requested. Supports inheritance of meta models

      constructor(readonly model: Function,
                  public identifiedBy = "id",
                  public api?,
                  public table = new TableConfigBuilder(),
                  public form = new FormConfigBuilder()) { }

      build(): CBDWebMetaModel {
        return new CBDWebMetaModel(
          this.model,
          this.identifiedBy,
          this.api,
          this.table.build(),
          this.form.build()
        );
      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the html code, I think you are missing to binding of displayedColumns array to the mat-table header.

Something like below :

[Screen shot of mat-table displayedColumns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzGjm.png)

Also, can you please check if there are any errors in the dev tools ?

Please let me know the outcome.

PS : I have used mat-table in several palces in my project and it is working great!

Comment: I have updated my code in the post. I have binding of displayedColumns array to the mat-table header.

Comment: This issue occurs in production and not in development.

Comment: @CluadiaHedda - The binding of the array ( dispalyedColumns ) in this case , should not be inside <ng-container>. It should be the last two lines before closing table tag ( </table>
Additionally, I believe that the all the mat-table related initializations should happen inside Constructor rather than in ngOninit lifecycle hook.
Since there is a good difference b/w two and I believe that this the reason you are seeing different behaviors in different regions.
Please let me know how it will go. I will really appreciate to get the feedback.

Comment: Is there any way I can reproduce this issue in development?

Comment: I see you are using 'async' pipe for column headers definition. 

I can think of regional difference while waiting for async response.

I would still recommend not to use <ng-container> for columns headers definition.
as mentioned earlier, I have using mat-table in multiple projects without any issues by following the same approach.

Comment: @CluadiaHedda - Checking if you were able to fix the problem ?